# better code structure for findViewById()

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I am curious about using the code in android like

```
findViewById(R.id.view_id).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

OR

```
findViewById(R.id.view_id).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
```

is this a good structure to use "findViewById" or add any listener on any view or should use it like

```
Button buttonA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.view_id);
buttonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its depends on you

Comment: both the ways it can be done

Comment: so using one of above make no difference in app performance or code execution?

Comment: No. Its only make your code less

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing in this case is consistency. To make your code readable it is good to think about these things and make code guidelines that apply to the whole project.

Aside from this here is my general rule:

if I need a view only once, I use it inline:

```
findViewById(R.id.view.id).someMethod();
```

But if I need it serveral times within one method, I create a local var:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.view_id);
view.someMethod();
view.someOtherMethod();
```

and if I need to use the view in several methods, I declare a class variable:

```
private View view;
...
this.view = findViewById(R.id.view_id);
view.someMethod();
view.someOtherMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

its depend on you

```
Button buttonA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.view_id);
//can be like this
buttonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

      }
});

//or like this
buttonA.setOnClickListener(new MyOwnClickListener());

public class MyOwnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

if you want more clearer view initialize, use ButterKnife

if you want even more clean view, use Kotlin with kotlin extension. :D

Answer (score 1):

I personally would recommend using a Library, that does this stuff for you.
For example, you could use [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/). To use it, add to your project gradle file these lines:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
```

Then, when you are in your Activity, you could define your Buttons like this:

```
@BindView(R.id.your_button_id)
Button myButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
  setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
  Butterknife.Bind(this);
  //From here on, your button is available.
}
```

You could also implement onClick-Listeners for your buttons with Butterknife's help:

```
@OnClick(R.id.yourButtonId)
public void yourOnClickMethod(View view) {
  // your logic
}
```

I would recommend using this, as it avoids a lot of boilerplate and Butterknife has some neat features. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not good way. You can use ButterKnife android library. You dont need 'findViewById' or 'setOnClickListener', trust me ;) Your code will be clean!

http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: I have used butterknife but can you give an example that how it is not a good way?

Comment: In your code, you must write findViewById for your components. But in butterknife, just @BindView(R.id.title) TextView title;' îs enough. And you must write setOnClickListener all action item. In butter knife, you write a function and add @OnClick(R.id.buttonId) annotation begin of it. No need setonClickListener. This will make your code understandable.ButterKnife have more properties, thats just a two properties.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's always easier to bind all views in onCreate so I have them in one place.

Another thing, which is useful is butterknife library. http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/